# Creating a build server for .NET and C/C++

Tags: build

I am interested in creating a build server for automating builds in .NET and C/C++.

I understand the basic structure of the system but I would like to know there is any open source of professional software out there that I can install on the server for performing automated builds.

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Subbu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Cruise Control (which I'm also using), there's also [UppercuT](http://code.google.com/p/uppercut/).

Answer (score 0):

I've used [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) with MSBuild pretty successfully. It runs on Java.

There's also [CruiseControl.Net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ccnet/) for running using the .NET platform.

Answer (score 0):

[TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) is really easy to use and setup.
It's a commercial product, but there is a free edition with basically no restrictions, except that the number of possible build configurations (=projects) is limited to 20. See the feature comparison [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/download/index.html?fromFeaturesTop).